# Are multiple integers stored in the same memory location to save space?

Tags: c, go, optimization, memory, cpu-registers

If I declare two 32bit integers in Go/C on a computer that has 64bit memory locations. Could they be stored in the same memory location? The left most 32bits stores the first integer, and the right most 32bits stores the second integer. Or is every variable you declare stored in its own memory location.

Put another way: `1000 x int32` uses the same amount of memory locations as `1000 x int64`?

Comment: A "register" isn't a "memory location"...

Comment: Thanks @BenWainwright. Updated. I thought memory was just a whole load of registers.

Comment: 64 bits addresses means the addresses are 64 bits long. They still refer to individual bytes, they can just address more of them than with 32 bits.

Comment: nope. the implicit reading and shifting would negate the memory saved by wasting cpu cycles.

Comment: There were, in the past, machines where "registers" were just fast memory (and thus had addresses): the PDP-10 was like this for instance. That's not the case in modern architecture, though.

Comment: @EmanuelP are you saying each 64bit address points to a byte (8 bits)? For some reason I thought a 64bit architecture meant addresses and memory locations are both 64bits long.

Answer (score 2):

Registers and RAM memory are two different things. Your compiler will normally decide which variables to keep where. In the case of RAM, if it uses 32 bits per variable, the addresses will still be different. It is certainly possible that it uses 64 bits and "wastes" 32 bits if that increases performance. For registers, a compiler would be allowed to use the low order and high order bits for different variables, but it will almost certainly not because that would degrade performance.

Comment: Thanks. So if the 32bits are "wasted" you use the same amount of RAM memory for an int32 and an int64? eg. `1000 x int32` uses the same amount of memory locations as `1000 x int64` in Go?

Comment: @Neil That is entirely possible. Memory that is aligned is often faster for the processor to fetch. It does depend a bit. An array has to be *continuous* and the `intN_t` types in `stdint.h` have to have an exact size, so 'int64_t x[1000];` will take more memory than its int32_t counterpart. Other than that, the compiler will choose an alignment and potentially padding depending on the architecture and usage pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> If I declare two 32bit integers in Go/C on a computer that has 64bit memory locations could they be stored in the same memory location?

No, of course not, because then they couldn't have distinct values.

64-bit architectures can still address every individual byte in memory. In C terms, incrementing a void pointer by one makes it point to the next byte, not the next qword. You just can address more individual bytes than with 32-bit addresses.

So a [1000]int32 is half as big as a [1000]int64:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    var x [1000]int32
    var y [1000]int64

    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(x)) // 4000
    fmt.Println(unsafe.Sizeof(y)) // 8000
}
```

Note that in Go this is an implementation detail and depends on the compiler, but no sane compiler would waste enormous amounts of memory by aligning everything on 8 bytes.

Comment: "In C terms, incrementing a pointer by one makes it point to the next byte, not the next qword". <- that is super interesting. thanks.

Comment: @Peter Did you mean "twice as *small* as"?

Comment: A pointer to a non-byte type will increment the pointer by the size of the type. So it depends on the size of the type. Void pointers will behave the same as byte pointers.